# Error to create an agent on Dialogflow - Permission denied

Tags: dialogflow-cx

The following error occurs when creating an agent within Dialogflow ES.
Permission denied to enable service [dialogflow.googleapis.com]
Help Token: AZ-7fWKrvHs7PzqZPCBn6lUHwQiUrrkT9ud87jAzeaw7HZu_nP-oQ44hkr_ZTq68NURKkq-V3FbY-...
How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you do not have the dialogflow.googleapis.com API enabled or you do not have permissions to create Agents. You can follow the process here: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/setup

Comment: Thanks, Xaviers, I appreciate your reply. But I enabled the Dialogflow API. As I'm not the project administrator, I asked for some permissions and one of them was to create agents. Maybe there are other permissions I need, but I don't really know what they are. I asked for permission to see the list of API keys, maybe that will help me.

Comment: you will need test-to-speech and speech-to-text permissions probably too

Comment: Having enable the API is one thing. Your user must also have permissions to do things in Dialogflow (e.g. create agent, edit flow, create version).  Your admin has to grant you a specific role (typically roles/dialogflow.consoleAgentEditor). See https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/access-control#df-console